# Angular CLI not detecting changes when running inside a container

Tags: angular, docker

Since two days, I'm experiencing a problem with Angular CLI: it's not detecting code changes when running inside a container. This applies to all of my projects. I'm running Docker Desktop on macOS 10.15.3. Adding --poll argument fixes the issue (polling time 5 secs), but this drains a lot of CPU power.

Someone else is sharing the same issue?

Comment: Source code equals with host's one: I see the changed files while I'm attached to container's shell.

Comment: Can you use a plain Node environment on your development system, without introducing Docker into the equation?

Comment: Hi @DavidMaze, thanks for you comment! I already have a working Node env on my laptop, but I need to manage several projects. This means switching Node version each time...this is why Docker is so helpful! Anyway, I've just solved the problem with a full shutdown of all containers. Thanks anyway!